# oil in my cooling system liquid is my TURBO damaged

Tags: engine, oil, cooling-system, turbocharger

I have a kia forte 5 sx 2016 with about 31000 miles on it. Last week the 4 spark plugs broke. I've got them changed under my guarantee. I knew something was wrong but the dealer didn't want to look into it. Not even 40 minutes into driving my engine heating gauge went to the top. I stopped the car, checked the oil level, no more oil, i then realized all my oil was in the cooling liquid system. Good news is, Kia is changing the motor. Since my turbo cools off with the cooling liquid and all the oil is in it, can this damage my turbo? can any other parts of my car be damaged due to this? thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I would think the turbo should be changed as part of the engine swap. Did you get the indication from the dealership they *wouldn't be changing it?*

Comment: They said they would change everything that got damaged, but i think they wont, they'll say its not part of the engin. Since the problem started, i've had problems with the dealership, when the spark plugs broke, they changed them without futher looking into the problem.

Comment: This is all being done under warranty, right? If so and they don't give you satisfaction, go straight to regional Kia management. They are the ones actually paying for the engine transplant, not the dealership. I'm pretty sure it would work the same in Canada as it would down here in the States. Another thing is, don't assume they won't. If you have questions, ask them pointed questions about what will be replaced. If you ask them directly, will it be the same turbo or will the new engine come with one? They'll usually tell you unless the service manager is being a complete turd.

Comment: Yes, all under warranty, i'll make sure to contact the service manager. Thanks a lot for the response!!! have a great day

Comment: Keep in mind that when under warranty, its in their best interest to make sure the new engine keeps working.  If they leave a faulty part in that ruins the new engine, they're still on the hook for _another_ warranty replacement, and they have to answer questions from the manufacturer as to why it happened again.

Comment: Great, already that they changed the 4 spark plugs without looking into the problem, just assuming the plugs had some kind of problem. Im no mechanic and i know spark plugs dont break for no reason, especially at 30000miles

Comment: Get it done at another dealership : they may be better...